# JPanels display problems

Tags: java, swing, jar, jframe, jpanel

I am working on a small game. I've almost finished it, but the remaining problems I face could be divided into three:

1. When I execute my game, nothings shows up on the window just a gray background, when I reduce it and click on it again, I find what normally I should see; and this problem with all the panels, for example to move from the game panel to the score panel I should reduce it again ...
2. It is slow ! especially if it needs to calculate score when I lose and seeds to display my updated `ScorePanel`.
3. I cannot execute my generated JAR file, I sought a solution for a while but in vain

Here are the three main classes of my code:

### JFrame Code

```
public class Fenetre extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu file = new JMenu("Fichier");
    private JMenuItem neew = new JMenuItem("Nouveau");
    private JMenuItem score = new JMenuItem("Score");
    private JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("Quitter");
    private JMenu about = new JMenu("About");
    private JMenuItem how = new JMenuItem("Règles");
    private JMenuItem who = new JMenuItem("Credit");
    private int i=1;
    private ScorePanel scorepan = new ScorePanel(900,650);
    private ReglesJeuPanel rgpan = new ReglesJeuPanel(900,650);
    private GamePanel gamepan = new GamePanel();
    private JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    private JPanel container = new JPanel();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("------------------------SAMAIKOM------------------------");
    private JTextArea texte = new JTextArea(    "Vous avez sept coups pour trouver le mot caché. Si vous réussissez, on recommence !\n" +
            "Plus vous trouvez de mots, plus votre score augmente. Alors, à vous de jouer !\n" +
            "Proverbe :\t« Pas vu, pas pris !\n" +
                "\tPris ! PENDU ! »");
public Fenetre(){
    this.setTitle("Le Pendu ...");
    this.setSize(900, 650);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    initMenu();
    initAcceuilPan();
    initListeners();
    this.setContentPane(container);
}

private void initMenu(){
    file.add(neew);
    file.add(score);
    file.addSeparator();
    file.add(quit);
    file.setMnemonic('F');
    neew.setMnemonic('N');
    neew.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    score.setMnemonic('S');
    score.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    quit.setMnemonic('Q');
    quit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));

    about.add(how);
    about.addSeparator();
    about.add(who);
    about.setMnemonic('A');
    how.setMnemonic('R');
    how.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
    who.setMnemonic('C');
    who.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));

    menu.add(file);
    menu.add(about);
    this.setJMenuBar(menu);
}

private void initListeners(){
    score.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            container.removeAll();
            container.add(scorepan);
        }
    });
    quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    how.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            container.removeAll();
            container.add(rgpan);
        }
    });
    neew.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            gamepan.setNewWord();
            gamepan.resetButtons();
            container.removeAll();
            container.add(gamepan);
        }
    });

    gamepan.addCustomListener(new CustomListener(){

        public void wordFound() {
                neew.doClick();
        }

        public void wordNotFound() {
            if(!ScorePanel.isScoreSuffisant())
            {
                container.removeAll();
                initAcceuilPan();
            }
            if(ScorePanel.isScoreSuffisant()){
                scorepan.initLeftPan();
                container.removeAll();
                container.add(scorepan);
            }
        }

    });


}

private void initAcceuilPan(){
    pan.removeAll(); // si on ne met pas cette methode, apres la réinisialisation du container si le mot n'a pas été trouvé on trouve 2 images!
    pan.setBackground(Color.white);
    pan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131868.jpg")));
    texte.setEditable(false);
    Font F1 = new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,20);
    Font F2 = new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,15);
    label.setFont(F1);
    texte.setFont(F2);
    container.setBackground(Color.white);
    container.add(label);
    container.add(pan);
    container.add(texte);
    //container.add(gamepan);

}



}
```

### GamePanel Code

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel{
private JPanel leftPan = new JPanel();
private JPanel rightPan = new JPanel();
private String[] letters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",};
private JButton Button[] = new JButton[26];

private JLabel label1;
private JLabel label2;
private JLabel label3;
private String mistakeslabel; // pour savoir si un traitement a été fais ou non sur le tWord ( pour les mistakes )
private ActionListener buttonListener;
private JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();

private Word randWord = new Word(); // mot aléatoire
private TreatedWord tWord = new TreatedWord(randWord.getRandWord());// mot aléatoire traité ( etoiles et tout ça )
private char clickedButton;// lettre tappée
private int mistakes = 0;
private int coups = 0;

private final List<CustomListener> customListener = new LinkedList<>(); //On crée une liste de CustomListener pour en ajouter autant qu'on veut(Via addCustomListener)

public GamePanel(){
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    initGamePan();
    initListeners();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(leftPan,BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.add(rightPan,BorderLayout.EAST);
}

public void initGamePan(){
    label1 = new JLabel("Nombre de mots trouvés : 0");
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label1.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,20));
    label1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));

    label2 = new JLabel("Score Actuel : 0 point");
    label2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label2.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,20));
    label2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));

    label3 = new JLabel(tWord.getStars());
    label3.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label3.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,30));
    label3.setForeground(Color.blue);
    label3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,50));

    mistakeslabel=label3.getText();

    leftPan.add(label1);
    leftPan.add(label2);
    leftPan.add(label3);
    for(int i=0;i<letters.length;i++){
        Button[i]= new JButton(letters[i]);
        leftPan.add(Button[i]);
    }

    leftPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460,650));
    leftPan.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    rightPan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420,650));
    rightPan.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

public void initListeners(){
    buttonListener= new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            clickedButton = ((JButton)(arg0.getSource())).getText().charAt(0); // on prend le bouton cliqué, on le convertis en string puis en char
            label3.setText(tWord.treatedWord(clickedButton));// on donne a la methode tretedWord de l'objet tWord le char clickedbutton pour faire le traitement sur le mot mystère
            ((JButton)(arg0.getSource())).setEnabled(false);
            if(mistakeslabel==label3.getText()){
                mistakes++;
                rightPan.removeAll();
                switch(mistakes){
                case 1 : rightPan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131870.jpg")));
                break;
                case 2 : rightPan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131871.jpg")));
                break;
                case 3 : rightPan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131872.jpg")));
                break;
                case 4 : rightPan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131873.jpg")));
                break;
                case 5 : rightPan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131874.jpg")));
                break;
                case 6 : rightPan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131875.jpg")));
                break;
                case 7 : rightPan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131876.jpg")));
                break;
                }
            }
            mistakeslabel=label3.getText();
            coups++;
            System.out.println(randWord.getRandWord());

            if(tWord.isFound()){
                String S;
                S=ScorePanel.updateScore(coups,mistakes);
                jop.showMessageDialog(null, "Bravo t'a trouvé le mot "+randWord.getRandWord()+" !\n en "+coups+" coups et "+mistakes+" erreur"+(mistakes>1 ? "s" : "")+S, "U don't Say B|", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                GamePanel.this.notifyWordFound(); // explications à la fin
            }
            if(mistakes==7){
                if(!ScorePanel.isScoreSuffisant())
                {
                    jop.showMessageDialog(null, "Score Insuffisant pour l'enregistrer ...", "hahahah wa l3iaaaan !", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                if(ScorePanel.isScoreSuffisant())
                {
                    String Sc;
                    Sc=jop.showInputDialog(null,"Entrez un pseudo","Mabikch",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    ScorePanel.updateScoreLeftPan(Sc);
                }
                GamePanel.this.notifyWordNotFound();
                mistakes=0;
            }
        }

    };
    for(int i=0;i<letters.length;i++){
        Button[i].addActionListener(buttonListener);
    }

}




public void setNewWord(){
    this.randWord = new Word();
    this.tWord = new TreatedWord(randWord.getRandWord());
    this.label3.setText(tWord.getStars());
    this.mistakeslabel=label3.getText();
    this.mistakes=0;
    this.rightPan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131869.jpg")));
}
public void resetButtons(){
    for(JButton B : this.Button){
        B.setEnabled(true);
    }
}


 public void addCustomListener(final CustomListener listener) {
        this.customListener.add(listener);
    }

 private void notifyWordFound(/* any data you could use */) {
        for(final CustomListener listener : this.customListener) {
            listener.wordFound(/* any data you could use */);
        }
    }
 private void notifyWordNotFound(/* any data you could use */) {
        for(final CustomListener listener : this.customListener) {
            listener.wordNotFound(/* any data you could use */);
        }
    }

}
```

### ScorePanel Code

```
public class ScorePanel extends JPanel{

private  JPanel rightpan = new JPanel();
private JPanel leftpan = new JPanel();
private static int[] scores = {200,100,100,100,50,50,50,25,15,15};
private static String players[] = {"Haytam lwa3er","Player1","Player2","Player3","Player4","Player5","Player6","Player7","Player8","Player9"};
private int[] policeSize = {30, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20};
private JLabel label;
private static int score=0;
private static int scoreTotal=0;

public ScorePanel(int w,int h){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h));
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    initLeftPan();
    rightpan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(430,650));
    rightpan.setBackground(Color.white);
    rightpan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("131876.jpg")));
    this.add(leftpan,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(rightpan,BorderLayout.EAST);

}
public void initLeftPan(){
    leftpan.removeAll();
    leftpan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(470,500));
    leftpan.setBackground(Color.white);
    for(int i=0;i<players.length;i++){
        label= new JLabel("                  "+players[i]+" : "+scores[i]+" pts "+"(1mot)"+"                  ");
        Font F1=  new Font("Comics Sans MS", Font.BOLD, policeSize[i]);
        label.setFont(F1);

        leftpan.add(label);
    }
}
public static String updateScore(int coups,int mistakes){
    switch(mistakes){
    case 0 : score = 100;
    break;
    case 1 : score = 50;
    break;
    case 2 : score = 35;
    break;
    case 3 : score = 25;
    break;
    case 4 : score = 15;
    break;
    case 5 : score = 10;
    break;
    case 6 : score = 5;
    break;
    }
    scoreTotal=scoreTotal+score;
    return "\n Vous parquez "+score+" Points\nScore Total : "+scoreTotal;
}
public static boolean isScoreSuffisant(){
    if(scoreTotal>=scores[9])return true;
    else return false;
}
public static void updateScoreLeftPan(String pseudo){
    for(int i=0;i<scores.length;i++){
        if(scoreTotal>=scores[i]){
            for(int j=scores.length-1;j>i-1;j--){
                if(scoreTotal>=scores[j] && j!=0){
                    scores[j]=scores[j-1];
                    players[j]= players[j-1];
                }
                if(j==i){scores[j]=scoreTotal; players[j]=pseudo;}
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}


}
```

Comment: SO works best for everyone is we deal with one question per question thread!  Please decide which one you want to deal with here, and split the other 2 into their own questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first one is, when I execute my game, nothings shows up on the
>   window just a gray background, when I reduce it and clic on it again,
>   I find what normally I should see; and this problem with all the
>   panels, for exemple to move from the game panel to the score panel I
>   should reduce it again ...

This is typically a symptom of calling `setVisible(true)` BEFORE you've actually added anything to the window...

> The third problem is that I cannot execute my generated JAR file, I
>   sought a sollution for a while but in vain

This probably because you've failed to supply the `Main-Class` entry to the mainfest file.  Take a look at [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

`==` is not how `String` comparison is done within Java, instead you want to use `String#equals`, for example...

```
if (mistakeslabel == label3.getText()) {...
```

Should be

```
if (mistakeslabel.equals(label3.getText())) {...
```

> The second problem is that it is slow ! especially if it needs to
>   calculate score when I lose and seeds to display my updated scorepanel
>   ...

This is unclear, but I suspect, that if you called `revalidate` and `repaint` after chaning the panels OR used a `CardLayout`, you might find this works better

Comment: Indeed when I changed the location of setVisible(true)' it worked properly, as for the second problem, I used a CardLayout` in my JFrame, and also revalidate in my GamePanel, both solved the problem thanx, But the JAR problem still persists, I followed the link, it works, but My JAR should be with the other files (images and a txt file) can't I make it all one file ? I don't wan't the user to access those files

Comment: When running eclipse, you should place your embedded resources in a "resources" directory within the project and place all your resources within in it. These should then be included by eclipse when it builds the project. You will then need to read theses resources using Class#getResource or Class#getResourceAsStream

Comment: Where do I add the `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` ??

Comment: There methods of Class, you can use getClass() of any instance of Object or Object.class if you don't have an instance

Comment: Which Object ?? the ones that uses ressources ? for exemple the JLabel in my JFrame ?

Comment: Any. The choice of object will affect relative paths, so I tend to use absolute paths `/path/to/resource/to/be/loaded/...`

Comment: Works for the photos but not for the txt file, I will ask a new question to describe the problem properly, thanx for the previous answers ! you rock \m/

Comment: Works for any type of embedded resource, contained with any of the Jar files or directories within the classpath. I use this approach to load XML files all the time

Comment: Well, maybe I misunderstood how to do it, here is how I did it :  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128053/exporting-a-jar-with-ressources  tell me if it isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the first problem. But for second and third problem, I can definitely help.

1. You have not used **Multithreading** in your game. Please remember that no game in Java is possible without using it.
2. Use an IDE like **Eclipse or NetBeans** for easily creating JAR files.

All the best !!

Comment: For the JAR file I used eclipse the problem is I that nothing happens when I double click it !
as for th `Multithreading` how do I proceed ?

Comment: Use Jarfix for repairing JAR files:                              [link](http://johann.loefflmann.net/downloads/jarfix.exe)