# Exporting a JAR with Ressources

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I was trying to solve this problem the whole day but in vain !!

Basically I want to export a JAR with `images` and a `txt` file (and latter maybe an `audio` file).

I found that I need to make a new folder within I should add my resources, I did.

then I found that I should use something like :

`pan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/131868.jpg"))));`

instead of `pan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/131868.jpg")));`   I did

but for my text file

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionnaire.txt"));`

I used `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader((getClass().getResource("dictionnaire.txt")).toString));` but I get a `NullPointerException`

and without it, when I make the JAR file and open it as `rar` I don't find my resource folder !!!! SOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An embedded resources can not be treated like a `File`, don't think of it like a file, it will only confuse you more, it is a "resource" and needs to be treated differently

Instead of

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionnaire.txt"));
```

or

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader((getClass().getResource("dictionnaire.txt")).toString));
```

You will need to use something like...

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("dictionnaire.txt"));
```

`Class#getResource` will return a `URL`, many objects are happy to deal with a `URL`, but it can be messy having to get a `URL`'s `InputStream`, so `Class#getResourceAsStream` makes it easier to achieve this in a single call

Comment: Ok, I did it, when I run it I have a `NullPointerException` at this line : 

`rightpan.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("data/131876.jpg"))));`

Comment: Two things, make sure the resource actually exists and try using `/data/131876.jpg` instead...

Comment: What is qualified name of the package which contains the image file: 131876.jpg?

Comment: Is `data` being included within the Jar when you build your application? Jars are just Zip based files, so you can unzip them to check

Comment: No it is not, I mentionned it in My question, Even if I added `data` throught `properties->java build path`

Comment: Try creating a `resources` directory and adding `data` directory to it...I've never used Eclipse, but "resources" get mentioned about a lot. You could try having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270197/java-in-eclipse-where-do-i-put-files-on-the-filesystem-that-i-want-to-load-usin

Comment: It worked !!! I followed the instructions in the link you gave me, Basically the stuff using `getResource` should be in the src folder, thanx man! you rock \m/